# How to write setHttpResponseCode() in magento 2 Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

In Magento 1.x I m writing below code in Observer -

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(403);
Mage::app()->getResponse()->clearBody();   
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendHeaders();
```

Now I want to write same functionality in Magento-2 Observer. Please let know what Injunctions need to implement and how to write above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to inject the following class in your observer constructor: `\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface` for example:

```
protected $_response;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
) {
    ...
    $this->_response = $response;
}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(403);
$this->_response->clearBody();
$this->_response->sendHeaders();
```

Comment: ahh.. you doing a great job

Comment: Thx ...Raphael its works..... :)